# How to find a minimum weight spanning tree for the following graph using prims algorithm

Tags: graph, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

[image: Graph]

Prim’s Algorithm

An algorithm for finding a minimum spanning tree.

- Begin by choosing any edge with smallest weight, putting it into the spanning tree.
- Successively add to the tree edges of minimum weight that are incident to a vertex already in the tree, never forming a simple circuit with those edges already in the tree.
- Stop when n − 1 edges have been added.

I know that you must start at node A. Also by giving a list of the
order in which nodes and/or edges are added.

But im not sure on the exact steps to find the minimum weight spanning tree.

Comment: Why do you think you need to start at node A? That's not what the first step in the algorithm says, is it?

Comment: @beaker that's what i was told, when you use prims algorithm, you must start at node A, for this question at least.

Comment: Then it's not Prim's algorithm. If you've been asked to do something else, then I suggest you talk to your TA and ask them if you're following their instructions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Select all unvisited edges from A

A - B = 2

A - E = 2

A - F = 5

**Find cheapest : A - B**

Select all unvisited edges from A and B

A - E = 2

A - F = 5

B - C = 1

B - E = 2

B - F = 4

**Find cheapest : B - C**

Select all unvisited edges from A, B and C

A - E = 2

A - F = 5

B - E = 2

B - F = 4

C - D = 4

C - E = 1

**Find cheapest : C - E**

Select all unvisited edges from A, B, C and E

A - E = 2

A - F = 5

B - E = 2

B - F = 4

C - D = 4

E - D = 3

E - F = 1

**Find cheapest : E - F**

Node D is the only unvisited node, so it can either be; D -E OR C - D.

Cheapest = E - D : 3

Now all nodes have been visited, remove unused edges

Minimum weight spanning tree would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw6DK.png)

Comment: thats how i would do it but im not sure if its the correct answer