# How to give a recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

Give a recursive algorithm btProd which takes as input a binary tree, and outputs
the value that is the product of the numbers contained in the binary tree. If the input is the null tree, then the algorithm should return null.

Algorithm btProd(P)

Require: Input is a tree P

1: btProd(null) ← 0

2: btProd(leaf x) ← x

3: btProd(node L x R) ← btProd(L) + x + btProd(R )

That's the way i would do it but i'm not sure if that's correct

Comment: What have you done thus far?

Comment: Because the multiplication is commutative you can traverse the tree any way you want and multiply all the nodes.

Comment: Please try out some steps and post what you tried

Comment: Add clarification directly to the question itself using [edit]. Comments ([and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43820666/1377097)) are the wrong place to make updates.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @beaker

Comment: Your algorithm seems to be fine except that it's not plus, you want the product, so you need to multiply in step 3.

Comment: Actually there is another problem, if a node has only one child the algo will return 0, so btProd(null) should return 1 (the neutral element of the multiplication) unless it is the root (then 0).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the product is commutative. Thus, you can traverse the tree in any order you like ([pre-,in-,post-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)). The recursion you motivated as pseudo-code seems correct, assuming that when you write `+ x +` you mean btProd(L) times btProd(R).